# how to check if list contain first element as <strong> via css

Tags: javascript, css

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li class="info">Testing Bold text in custom bullets</li>
    <li class="info"><strong>Testing</strong> Bold text in custom bullets</li>
    <li class="info">Testing <strong>Bold</strong> text in custom bullets</li>
    <li class="info">Testing Bold <strong>text</strong> in custom bullets</li>
    <li class="info">Testing Bold text <strong>in</strong> custom bullets</li>
    <li class="info">Testing Bold text in <strong>custom</strong> bullets</li>
    <li class="info">Testing Bold text in custom <strong>bullets</strong></li>
    <li class="info">Testing Bold text in custom bullets</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Above HTML is dynamically generated, If `<strong>` comes first in `li` (e.g. 2nd `<li>` ) then only I need to do some styling.

Can you please advise if it can be possible via CSS or other alternative?

Answer (score 1):

CSS isn't really made for this case, but it would be possible with JavaScript.

Really the best thing to do is structure your HTML more semantically, and use a class where you need it.

But since you're generating the HTML dynamically and don't have control over the output, here is a solution with JS.

```js
    document.querySelectorAll('ul li').forEach(element => {
        if (element.innerHTML.startsWith('<strong>') ) {
            element.querySelector('strong').style = 'color:red'
        }
    })
```

```html
    <div class="container">
        <ul>
            <li class="info">Testing Bold text in custom bullets</li>
            <li class="info"><strong>Testing</strong> Bold text in custom bullets</li>
            <li class="info">Testing <strong>Bold</strong> text in custom bullets</li>
            <li class="info">Testing Bold <strong>text</strong> in custom bullets</li>
            <li class="info">Testing Bold text <strong>in</strong> custom bullets</li>
            <li class="info">Testing Bold text in <strong>custom</strong> bullets</li>
            <li class="info">Testing Bold text in custom <strong>bullets</strong></li>
            <li class="info">Testing Bold text in custom bullets</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: thanks for feedback. but in my case, I can not  structure my HTML. otherwise, it could be simple for me.  So, I'm looking alternative approach to achieve same via CSS (more preferably) or JavaScript for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript you can check the first Node of each `<li>` and apply a class or inline style to it

Following also accounts for empty text nodes as a result of line breaks in the html

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.container li').forEach(el => {
  let firstNode = el.childNodes[0];
  // account for empty text nodes
  while (firstNode.nodeType === 3 && !firstNode.textContent.trim()) {
    firstNode = firstNode.nextSibling
  }
  if (firstNode.nodeName === 'STRONG') {
    firstNode.classList.add('first-bold')
  }
})
```

```css
.first-bold {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li class="info">Testing Bold text in custom bullets</li>
    <li class="info"><strong>Testing</strong> Bold text in custom bullets</li>
    <li class="info">Testing <strong>Bold</strong> text in custom bullets</li>
    <li class="info">Testing Bold <strong>text</strong> in custom bullets</li>
    <li class="info">Testing Bold text <strong>in</strong> custom bullets</li>
    <li class="info">

      <strong>Testing</strong> Bold text in <strong>custom</strong> bullets
    </li>
    <li class="info">Testing Bold text in custom <strong>bullets</strong></li>
    <li class="info">
      Testing Bold text in custom bullets</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

<s>`ul li:first-child strong { ... }` will do the trick.</s>

Sorry, I misread your question. What you want to do isn't really possible in CSS, as far as I know. Best thing to do is have whatever's generating the HTML add a class with the styling you want when it puts a `<strong>` element at the start of a list item.

Comment: This would select the `strong` tag in the first `li` in the list. The OP wants to select the `strong` tag for all `li`'s in the list, but only if they are the very first thing in the `li` (including text).

Comment: This selector matches nothing in the given HTML, since the first `li` child does not have a `strong` descendent.

Comment: Oh my god, you're right, I misread. Dang. I'll edit.

Answer (score -2):

You can apply below style sheet to recognize first child with strong tag:

```
li:first-child > strong {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: `first-child` does not consider text nodes. This will not solve what OP is asking

Comment: This would select the `strong` tag in the first `li` in the list. The OP wants to select the `strong` tag for all `li`'s in the list, but only if they are the very first thing in the `li` (including text).

Comment: can you please provide some example of what you want to say

Comment: The question already has examples and a clear definition of what is needed.